# How to get DST Offset to be consistent on local machine vs server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dst

I'm using ActiveSupport's Timezone class to find the offset of a Timezone like so.

```
novdate = Date.new(2012,11,04)
offset_in_seconds = ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Eastern Time (US & Canada)'].at(novdate.to_time.midnight+3.hours).utc_offset
```

The problem is that offset_in_seconds is different on my local machine and on a heroku server. I'm not sure why this is happening. I've set config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)' in my rails application.rb file. How can I accurately and consistently get a timezone offset for a given date? I've been adding 3 hours to the time above because the time should have been changed from DST to non-DST at 3:00am on a given date.

-- display from my local rails console --

```
novdate = Date.new(2012,11,04)
ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Eastern Time (US & Canada)'].at(novdate.to_time.midnight+1.hours)
 => Sun, 04 Nov 2012 01:00:00 EDT -04:00 
ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Eastern Time (US & Canada)'].at(novdate.to_time.midnight+2.hours)
 => Sun, 04 Nov 2012 01:00:00 EST -05:00 
ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Eastern Time (US & Canada)'].at(novdate.to_time.midnight+3.hours)
 => Sun, 04 Nov 2012 02:00:00 EST -05:00
```

-- output from a heroku rails console ---

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Eastern Time (US & Canada)'].at(novdate.to_time.midnight+4.hours)
=> Sun, 04 Nov 2012 00:00:00 EDT -04:00
ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Eastern Time (US & Canada)'].at(novdate.to_time.midnight+5.hours)
=> Sun, 04 Nov 2012 01:00:00 EDT -04:00
ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Eastern Time (US & Canada)'].at(novdate.to_time.midnight+6.hours)
=> Sun, 04 Nov 2012 01:00:00 EST -05:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the `to_time` method of `date` will not respect your timezone with that syntax.

If you look at [the documentation for `to_time`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-to_time) you can see it converts it to local time to the server.

Chances are the heroku server has a different time zone configured to your local machine (note this is not the `config.time_zone` setting)

This should work:

```
[24] pry(main)> Time.use_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)') {
[24] pry(main)*   novdate.to_time_in_current_zone()  
[24] pry(main)* }  
=> Sun, 04 Nov 2012 00:00:00 EDT -04:00
[25] pry(main)>
```